# python.NLTK (WindowDiff and PK) vs python.Segeval (WindowDiff and PK)

Tags: python, nltk, metrics, text-segmentation

**Python NLTK implementation of Beeferman's PK and WindowDIFF are getting complete different results from python segeval implementation of both.**

Using the same parameters.

```
hyp: 0100100000
ref: 0101000000
k=2
PK's SegEval:0.2222222
PK's NLTK:0.111111111

hyp: 111111
ref: 100100
k=2
PK's SegEval:0.4
PK's NLTK:0.64
```

This could lead different research results for who use it.
Why I am getting different results with PK in these 2 Implementations? PK has to have just one result.

Comment: I'd point out the bug, [but it appears you're already aware that one of these was likely coded wrong.](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/280) You can see that even in February 2013 the issues with NLTK's implementation of PK are still unresolved.

Comment: You're right. Installing the new version direct from github give me your updates. 

It is still different in the first case.

Comment: @MatheusAraujo I would email David Doukhan, his email address is in that thread (first dot last at gmail).

Comment: @MatheusAraujo I'd be willing to bet he never got around to fixing it as promised. I'd trust segeval over NLTK's implementation.

Comment: Thanks @Daи. I will email him anyway.
NLTK is too important for python world to let those metrics wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly, something go wrong with how you call the NLTK functions or you're using an old version of NLTK.

I'm getting the same results for NLTK as what you've shown in segeval:

```
>>> from nltk.metrics.segmentation import pk
>>> hyp = '0100100000'
>>> ref = '0101000000'
>>> pk(hyp, ref, 2)
0.2222222222222222
>>> hyp = '111111'
>>> ref = '100100'
>>> pk(hyp, ref, 2)
0.4
```

My nltk version:

```
>>> nltk.__version__
'3.0.5'
```

Do this:

```
$ pip install -U nltk
```